# How to obtain the numbered list of languages loaded by Babel

Tags: babel, languages

In the good old days, Babel used to provide the list of languages loaded:

```
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, loaded.
```

After upgrading to TeXLive 2016, now I only get this:

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 53 language(s) loaded.
```

Is there some way to return to the previous system, and obtain the list of languages, in the order they are loaded? I would very much appreciate that.

The reason is, I'm using the `\language` identifier manually in some cases (`\language=13` to switch to language 13, for example). Of course I know that the `\language` identifier can change from one format compilation to the other and that I "normally" shouldn't be using it. But I want to use it on my own risk, for my own files in my own system, and I would be grateful if babel allowed me to have this very valuable information. So if there is some change in the babel code I can do to restore that information, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to know which languages have been loaded, it's easy:

```
\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}
```

And then just look at the log file.

Comment: That's great!!! Thank you. It makes sense that when you remove an important feature you give users the possibility to restore it by some option.

Answer (score 3):

The babel format also stores the language list in `\bbl@languages`. They are stored in the format:

```
\bbl@elt{<language name>}{<number>}{<pattern file or empty for alias name>}{<empty>}
```

Application example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  vmargin=10mm,
  includefoot,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

  \makeatletter
  \@ifundefined{bbl@languages}{
    \emph{The language/pattern list of babel is not available.}
  }{
    \section*{The language/pattern list of babel}
    \def\bbl@elt#1#2#3#4{%
      \ifx\PrevNumber\relax
      \else
        \ifnum\PrevNumber=#2 %
        \else
          \midrule
        \fi
      \fi
      \gdef\PrevNumber{#2}%
      \typeout{* #2 #1\ifx\relax#3\relax\else\space(#3)\fi}%
      #2&#1&\texttt{#3}\\%
    }
    \global\let\PrevNumber\relax
    \begin{longtable}[l]{rll}
      \bbl@languages
    \end{longtable}
  }
  \makeatother

\end{document}
```

The terminal shows:

```
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.

* 0 english (hyphen.tex)
(/cygdrive/c/Users/one/tl/tldevsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmtt.fd)
* 0 usenglish
* 0 USenglish
* 0 american
* 1 dumylang (dumyhyph.tex)
* 2 nohyphenation (zerohyph.tex)
* 3 german-x-2014-05-21 (dehypht-x-2014-05-21.tex)
* 3 german-x-latest
* 4 ngerman-x-2014-05-21 (dehyphn-x-2014-05-21.tex)
* 4 ngerman-x-latest
* 5 afrikaans (loadhyph-af.tex)
* 6 ancientgreek (loadhyph-grc.tex)
* 7 ibycus (ibyhyph.tex)
* 8 arabic (zerohyph.tex)
* 9 armenian (loadhyph-hy.tex)
* 10 basque (loadhyph-eu.tex)
* 11 bulgarian (loadhyph-bg.tex)
* 12 catalan (loadhyph-ca.tex)
* 13 pinyin (loadhyph-zh-latn-pinyin.tex)
* 14 coptic (loadhyph-cop.tex)
* 15 croatian (loadhyph-hr.tex)
* 16 czech (loadhyph-cs.tex)
* 17 danish (loadhyph-da.tex)
* 18 dutch (loadhyph-nl.tex)
* 19 ukenglish (loadhyph-en-gb.tex)
* 19 british
* 19 UKenglish
* 20 usenglishmax (loadhyph-en-us.tex)
* 21 esperanto (loadhyph-eo.tex)
* 22 estonian (loadhyph-et.tex)
* 23 ethiopic (loadhyph-mul-ethi.tex)
* 23 amharic
* 23 geez
* 24 farsi (zerohyph.tex)
* 24 persian
* 25 finnish (loadhyph-fi.tex)
* 26 french (loadhyph-fr.tex)
* 26 patois
* 26 francais
* 27 friulan (loadhyph-fur.tex)
* 28 galician (loadhyph-gl.tex)
* 29 georgian (loadhyph-ka.tex)
* 30 german (loadhyph-de-1901.tex)
* 31 ngerman (loadhyph-de-1996.tex)
* 32 swissgerman (loadhyph-de-ch-1901.tex)
...
* 80 welsh (loadhyph-cy.tex)
```

And the typeset result, first page:

> [image: Result, page 1]

Answer (score 2):

I can offer the following code that reads the `language.dat` and steps a counter when necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlanguagenumber}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_yannis_language_list_prop { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\listlanguages}{}
 {
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_yannis_language_list_prop
   {
    ##1~=~##2 \par
   }
 }

\ior_new:N \yannis_language_file_stream
\int_new:N \g_yannis_language_number_int
\prop_new:N \g_yannis_language_list_prop

\int_gset:Nn \g_yannis_language_number_int { -1 } % first language is 0

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yannis_language_number:
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \yannis_language_file_stream { language.dat }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \yannis_language_file_stream
   {
    % check if an empty line slipped in, otherwise go on
    \tl_if_blank:nF { ##1 }
     {
      \__yannis_language_read:f { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yannis_language_read:n
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF =
   { \__yannis_language_alias:w } % if the line begins with =
   { \__yannis_language_real:w }  % normal language
   #1 \q_stop % the line contents and a terminator
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__yannis_language_read:n { f }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yannis_language_alias:w #1 \q_stop
 {
  \typeout { #1~=~\int_eval:n { \g_yannis_language_number_int } }
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_yannis_language_list_prop
   { #1 }
   { \int_eval:n { \g_yannis_language_number_int } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yannis_language_real:w #1 ~ #2 \q_stop
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_yannis_language_number_int
  \typeout { #1~=~\int_eval:n { \g_yannis_language_number_int } }
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_yannis_language_list_prop
   { #1 }
   { \int_eval:n { \g_yannis_language_number_int } }
 }

%% make the list; need to make the space a space
\AtBeginDocument{ \yannis_language_number: }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listlanguages

Welsh is \getlanguagenumber{welsh}

\end{document}
```

You can also say `\language=\getlanguagenumber{italian}` (although it would be simpler to do `\language=\csname l@italian\endcsname`.

It's not necessary to do `\listlanguages`, because the same information is printed on the terminal.

```
english = 0
usenglish = 0
USenglish = 0
american = 0
dumylang = 1
nohyphenation = 2
german-x-2014-05-21 = 3
german-x-latest = 3
ngerman-x-2014-05-21 = 4
ngerman-x-latest = 4
afrikaans = 5
ancientgreek = 6
ibycus = 7
arabic = 8
armenian = 9
basque = 10
[...]
thai = 77
turkish = 78
turkmen = 79
ukrainian = 80
uppersorbian = 81
welsh = 82
```

which agrees with

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
```

issued at startup.

Complicated? Hey, with the old setup you had to count manually and ignore aliases! `;-)`

Comment: The main drawback is `language.dat` could be modified. This is the very reason `babel` takes a “snapshot” and stores it in the format.

Comment: @JavierBezos A mismatch would mean it's time to run `fmtutil-sys --all`

Comment: Yeah, indeed :-).